# Setting RowSource of a Chart in a Microsoft Access 2010 Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have chart inside a report in Microsoft Access 2010 that gets its RecordSource via VBA in the OnLoad of the report. The reason is that I have a form where the user can select what to include in the report. So the query that is set in VBA is

```
Me.Chart01.RowSource = "xxxx WHERE tbl_cars.ID In (" & IDs & ");"
Me.Chart01.Requery
DoCmd.Requery
```

The problem is that the graph does not update. After doing `MsgBox Me.Chart01.RowSource` both before and after where I set the RowSource, the SQL seems to be correct. It works perferctly when I remove the In() part and try it in the Query Design.

(I load the RecordSource of the report the same way, and it works.)

Are the charts in Access too poor to be able to do this, or is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reports don't refresh like forms, so if the chart is unbound you'll have to take care and place the code changing the row source in an event which occurs before the report is rendered like the Format or Print event. I'm assuming the IDs you're including in the SQL string are numeric and not strings.

Comment: I figured it out.. I did WHERE CarID instead of where CarsID... It told me that the query hadn't changed when in fact it had. Wrong error message... Well, glad it works now anyway, and thanks for trying to help! It was of help because I learned that the problem wasn't that I couldn't get it to reload as I wanted it to.